# tslint ter-indent for function call with objects

Tags: tslint

How can I configure tslint rule `ter-indent` to not have this error?

```
Object
  .assign(
    {},
    {
      a: 'a',
    },
  );
```

would give ts lint error "Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4. (ter-indent)tslint(1)" on line 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding variable like this:

```
const extraData = {
    a: 'a',
};

Object
   .assign(
    {},
    extraData,
  );
```

Also you can try to experiment with [ter-indent rule](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules/blob/master/src/docs/rules/terIndentRule.md)